# Scala Play error loading assets

Tags: angularjs, scala, playframework

Whenever I try to load assets as described in the documentation, found [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/AssetsOverview), under "using configuration and AssetsFinder", I keep getting the following error:

> angular-1.6.4.min.js:sourcemap:202 Refused to apply inline style
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-1PxuDsPyGK6n+LZsMv0gG4lMX3i3XigG6h0CzPIjwrE='), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that
>   'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
>   fallback.

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong, or how to get around this? It seems strange that this error should occur....

EDIT:

From the answer provided by NBoo, I attempted to specify a CSP header with:

```
Ok("Index").withHeaders(SecurityHeadersFilter.CONTENT_SECURITY_POLICY_HEADER -> "default-src 'unsafe-inline'")
```

I've set `play.filters.headers.allowActionSpecificHeaders = true`
but now I get errors on other scripts.

Answer (score 1):

As from 2.6.x version Play enables the security headers filter by default. And therefore your page get's blocked by this filter. Take a look at this documentation:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/SecurityHeaders

You need to use Content-Security-Policy header among other headers.